# How to combine ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener and GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener properly?

Tags: android, gesture, gestures, gesture-recognition

My app needs to detect simple gestures (scroll, tap, long tap), and pinch zoom. Either detector works fine on its own - `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` for tap / scroll and `ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` for pinch zoom. The problem is combining the two. More specifically, it is very hard to start pinch zoom so that a couple of `onScroll` events are not generated before `onScaleBegin`.

Is there any good way to fix this? The only solution I can think about is buffer a few events before processing them (event queue), and discard `onScroll` / `onTap` without processing once `onScaleBegin` is detected. But that would introduce input lag (which my app already has and I don't want to make it even worse).

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean res = mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    if (!mScaleGestureDetector.isInProgress()) {
        res = mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly how I do it. The problem is, you can't place both fingers on the screen at the same moment. You will put one finger and then a second finger. If in the meantime your first finger moves slightly - that's `onScroll`.

Comment: so add some threshold in onScroll method

Comment: There is some threshold. I'm fine-tuning it right now, but it doesn't seem like a good solution either.

Comment: what values of distanceX/Y are we talking about?

Comment: On the order of {+/-2.0, +/-40.0} when I'm pinching vertically as I usually do.

Comment: Hmm, i dont think you can avoid this, any app i saw that uses pinch to scale suffer from this and it is no such problem

Comment: Another possibility is to keep track of the old position, prior to the start of scrolling. When a scale event is detected, cancel the effect of scrolling, and revert the position back to the old position. In this way, there is no extra lag for plain scroll, and scaling will happen in place.

Comment: I think it should be `res = res | mGestureDetector.onTouch()` so if scale wanted to return true, you return true.